# Why is the distinction between replacement and substitution important?

Tags: logic

I'm reading Exner/Rosskopf's: *Logic in Elementary Mathematics*.

They argue that there is *replacement* which seems to be a mapping from the set of variables to the set of formulas. As an example:

$$A\vee¬A\tag*{$A\mapsto(P\to Q) $}$$

$$[P\to Q]\vee¬[P\to Q]$$

As for *substitution*, it seems to be a mapping from the set of atomic formulas to the set of formulas, for example:

$$¬(PQ) \leftrightarrow ¬P\vee¬Q\tag*{$P\mapsto ¬P \\Q\mapsto¬Q$}$$

$$¬(¬P¬Q) \leftrightarrow ¬¬P\vee¬¬Q$$

And in previous exercises, it is seen that: $¬¬A=A.$ But we can't use replacement due to its definition, but we can use substitution and deduce that:

$$¬(¬P¬Q) \leftrightarrow P\vee Q$$

But why is this distinction important? The atomic formulas also appear as formulas and hence, we could have only the principle of substitution. So why is replacement important?

Comment: To be honest, I don't really understand why they're drawing the distinction either. But it's possible that it's useful for some technical reason down the road. I wouldn't worry about it too much, though, if I were you.

Comment: It seems that *replacement* is the operation that produces formulas from *schema* (putting formulas in place of "placeholders") while *subsitution* acts on formulas.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general, it is not so important: more recent treatments of mathematical logic do not need it.

See §2.1.: the letters $P, Q, R$ are used as *placeholders* for complete statements, i.e. they are *propositional variables*.

In §2.10, *replacement* is defined as the operation that produce from a formula $\mathcal F$ a new formula $\mathcal G$ replacing in $\mathcal F$ every occurrence of a *placeholder* $A$ with a formula $\mathcal A$.

Your first example with $A \lor \lnot A$ is correct.

We have to consider the comment : every formula derived by *replacement* from a valid formula (i.e. a *tautology*) is valid.

In §2.11 we have *substitution*: in this case "partial" replacement of sub-formulae is allowed, i.e. zero or more (some but not necessarily all) occurrences of a sub-formula $\mathcal A$ with an *equivalent* formula $\mathcal B$ into a formula $\mathcal U$ to get a new formula $\mathcal U^*$ wich is equivalent to the original one.

---

The issue is to have a *rule of replacement* that allows for the lack of a modern concept of *schema*.

If we want to express the "generality" of e.g. *excluded middle*, current presentations use schematic letters to formulate in the meta-theory the principle:

> $\varphi \lor \lnot \varphi$.

We use it to "generate" all the needed instances of the law "replacing" the schematic letters with formulae of the calculus: $P \lor \lnot P, (P \to Q) \lor \lnot (P \to Q), \ldots$

If, as in the text, we operate at the "calculus level", all the above are different formulae. Thus the only way to express the "generality" of logical laws is to introduce a *rule of replacement* that allows us to (potentially) produce all the instances from a "basic" one.

---

You can compare it with the more terse (and rigorous) treatment by :

- Alonzo Church, [Introduction to Mathematical Logic](https://books.google.it/books?id=KJbKCwAAQBAJ&pg=PA72), Princeton (1956), page 69-on:

> The rules of inference are the two following:
>
> > *100. From $[A \supset B]$ and $A$ to infer $B$    (*Rule of modus ponens*.)
> >
> > *101. From $A$, if $b$ is a variable [ a *propositional letter*: $p,q,r,\ldots$], to infer $S^b_B A$ [ where $S^b_B A$ is the formula which results by substitution of $B$ for each occurrence of $b$ throughout $A$]  (*Rule of substitution*.)

Comment: Wait, according to the book, it could be all occurrences. Unless this is something not too visible in there.

Comment: @OppaHilbertStyle - "it could be all"; exactly: fixed.